# Elements out of position when loading website

Tags: html, css

When I load https://wwww.customlogoshop.com the text is moved up and then slams back down into position when it's loading. I would much rather it load like my logo design page.

Here's a screenshot of the website when loading and when loaded [Website side by side. Left is loading. Right is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVwSP.jpg)

I am not sure what code to provide as I feel there may be many elements worth checking out. FYI the header has a fixed height of 800px and this made the image load without any movement.

The text in the middle is my only issue.

Apologies for lack of code provided but I hope the screenshots help.

Thanks!

Comment: External links to code and images are not allowed on SO. You must show a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

Your parallax resource isn't loaded when your site shows up, suggestions:
• host the resource yourself and with a CDN like Cloudflare have the resource cached both on their CDN and to client computers so it loads instantly.
• design the website without the resource then implement the resource again.